# Any good hive plugin tutorials?

Tags: java, plugins, hive

I'm looking to write some plugins for Apache Hive. Does anyone have suggestions for good starting points or tutorials? I did a google search but the results were a bit sparse.

Comment: "Results were a bit sparse"... because there aren't a whole lot of people writing Hive plugins.  SUGGESTION: Look on the [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/home.html) ... and just look at some of the plugins that are available

Answer (score 2):

When I started looking into Hive, I enjoyed this video:

http://vimeo.com/29732341

The Facebook article about it is also a great source of information:

http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/2/vldb09-938.pdf

Also, you can check an introduction I made here:

http://girlincomputerscience.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/apache-hive.html

Comment: Think how amazing all your answers would be if you put the content of your blog in your answer, and said "check out my profile page for all my stuff" ?

Comment: Sorry that you fell that way. I was really trying to help.

Comment: You are really helping, please continue to do so